# Error trying to connect useRef eventListeners in TypeScript/JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, addeventlistener, event-listener

Using typescript, attempting to connect eventListener to a container using useRef and useEffect hooks. The error we are seeing is:  **No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(type: keyof HTMLElementEventMap, listener: (this: HTMLDivElement, ev: WheelEvent | MouseEvent | UIEvent | Event | ClipboardEvent | ... 12 more ... | TransitionEvent) => any, options?: boolean | ... 1 more ... | undefined): void | undefined', gave the following error.
Argument of type '"WheelEvent"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof HTMLElementEventMap'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject, options?: boolean | AddEventListenerOptions | undefined): void | undefined', gave the following error.
Argument of type '(e: WheelEvent) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'EventListenerOrEventListenerObject'.
Type '(e: WheelEvent) => void' is not assignable to type 'EventListener'.
Types of parameters 'e' and 'evt' are incompatible.
Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'WheelEvent': deltaMode,**

```
const zoomRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)

useEffect(() => {
    zoomRef?.current?.addEventListener('WheelEvent', scroll)
    return () => {
      zoomRef?.current.removeEventListener('WheelEvent', scroll)
    }
  }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no event named "WheelEvent", it's "wheel".

```
useEffect(() => {
    const currentZoomRef = zoomRef?.current;

    currentZoomRef?.addEventListener("wheel", scroll);

    return () => {
      currentZoomRef?.removeEventListener("wheel", scroll);
    };
}, []);
```

The typescript error is caused by the definition of "scroll" function, the parameter should have the type WheelEvent

```
const scroll = (e: WheelEvent) => {
   console.log(e);
};
```

A working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/black-rain-t6m2x?file=/src/App.tsx).